# Sabre EnhancedAirBookRQ Upgrade from 3.1.0 to 3.8.0

Tags: php, soap, sabre

I am upgrading our Sabre EnhancedAirBookRQ from v3.1.0 to 3.8.0, I have checked with sabre api docs, but couldn't find any changes in request structure. When I call the soap api using php *CURL* with version changed to v3.8.0, get *CURL error 22*

**Request**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EnhancedAirBookRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/eab/v3_1" version="3.8.0" IgnoreOnError="true" HaltOnError="true">
   <OTA_AirBookRQ>
      <HaltOnStatus Code="NO" />
      <HaltOnStatus Code="NN" />
      <HaltOnStatus Code="UC" />
      <HaltOnStatus Code="US" />
      <OriginDestinationInformation>
         <FlightSegment FlightNumber="9862" DepartureDateTime="2017-08-28T02:10:00" NumberInParty="1" Status="NN" ResBookDesigCode="B">
            <DestinationLocation LocationCode="PVG" />
            <Equipment AirEquipType="73H" />
            <MarketingAirline Code="MU" FlightNumber="9862" />
            <OperatingAirline Code="FM" />
            <OriginLocation LocationCode="KUL" />
         </FlightSegment>
      </OriginDestinationInformation>
      <RedisplayReservation NumAttempts="2" WaitInterval="6000" />
   </OTA_AirBookRQ>
   <OTA_AirPriceRQ>
      <PriceRequestInformation Retain="true">
         <OptionalQualifiers>
            <PricingQualifiers>
               <PassengerType Code="ADT" Quantity="1" />
            </PricingQualifiers>
         </OptionalQualifiers>
      </PriceRequestInformation>
   </OTA_AirPriceRQ>
   <PostProcessing IgnoreAfter="false">
      <RedisplayReservation />
   </PostProcessing>
</EnhancedAirBookRQ>
```

Can any body tell me whats wrong with the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to update the version number in xmlns attribute of EnhancedAirBookRQ element.

```
xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/eab/v3_1"
```

to

```
xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/eab/v3_8"
```

updating it to correct version fixed the problem.